# ¿Cómo convertir de json a string en golang y echo?

Tags: go, echo

Tengo un json que recibo por post

```
{"endpoint" : "asistencia"}
```

Este lo recibo asi

```
json_map := make(map[string]interface{})
```

Ahora necesito asignarlo a una variable como string pero no se como se hace.

```
endpoint := c.String(json_map["endpoint"]) //Esto no funciona
```

No se como se debe hacer soy nuevo en golang

Answer (score 1):

Existe un metodo especifico en la [librería oficial](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) de golang. Te recomiendo que lo investigues porque puedes "descodificar" datos estructurados directamente. Para tu ejemplo, el script completo sería algo así:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    myJsonString := `{"endpoint" : "asistencia"}`
    json_map := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJsonString), &json_map)
    endpoint := json_map["endpoint"]
    fmt.Println(endpoint)
}
```